# Installation of Ubuntu with Wubi fails at around 75-80% completion

Tags: system-installation, wubi

I am trying to install Ubuntu using Wubi(12.10), but it fails and I don't know why.

It progresses to around 75% - 80% of the installation then fails.

I tried other Wubi versions too, including 12.04.

While installing, it shows amd64 installer, but on the Ubuntu website, we are not provided with any options to choose our architecture except the operating system.

My desktop configuration is:

- Windows 7
- HDD capacity: 500GB
- RAM capacity: 3GB
- processor: Intel dual core 2 xGhz

Comment: Please copy your log file (from the `%TEMP%` directory called `wubi-12.10-rev273.log`) to http://paste.ubuntu.com and add the pastebin address to your question.

Answer (score 0):

- Download iso from Ubuntu site and download wubi installer (don't engage it yet).
- Put iso file and wubi.exe in same folder in Windows and run wubi.exe.
- If you do that and if the iso is ok (wubi will do a checksum on the iso), wubi will do the installation from the iso file, and not download Ubuntu again.

Wubi has a problem. If you have a 64-bit CPU and low RAM it will download the 64-bit OS.

Comment: 12.04.2 wubi.exe can't install from a 64-bit ISO due to a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1134770).

Comment: yes, same bug is been on 12.04.1 when is relesed. wubi is slightly behind relece cycle and newest LTS wubi.exe is supported for 12.04.01 for now. for example, you have wubi installer packed on iso file. dont use that, download from the site. many windows user mont the iso on damon-tools for example after decompress iso and extrats wubi.exe from that. that is wrong way and may result istall damage ubuntu  system...